# "Null check operator used on a null value"

Tags: flutter

I get such an error in Flutter. What error I get is written in the title. I am also sending you my codes. I would appreciate your help.

```
class CustomizedTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        enableSuggestions: isPassword! ? false : true,
        autocorrect: isPassword! ? false : true,
        obscureText: isPassword ?? true,
        controller: myController,
        cursorColor: cursorColor,
        style: GoogleFonts.spaceMono(
          color: textColor,
        ),
        keyboardType: isPassword!? TextInputType.visiblePassword : TextInputType.emailAddress,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: hintText,
          hintStyle: GoogleFonts.spaceMono(
            color: hintStyleTextColor,
          ),
          labelText: lableText,
          labelStyle: GoogleFonts.spaceMono(
            color: lableStyleTextColor,
          ),
          prefixIcon: SvgPicture.asset(
            svgIcon,
            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
            height: 40,
            width: 40,
          ),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: borderColor,
              width: 1,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              10.0,
            ),
          ),
          fillColor: textFormFieldFillColor,
          filled: true,
          suffixIcon: isPassword! ? IconButton(
            icon: SvgPicture.asset(
              iPasswordVisible,
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ) : null,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I deleted the final parameters and threw them to you because the site does not allow too many lines of code.

I asked Chatgpt and Brad, and as an extra, I did what they said on the internet, but I didn't get any results. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for your use case

This will remove your `null check operator used on a null value` error because we are not using any `nullable` value in the code below.

```
class CustomizedTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
const CustomizedTextFormField({required this.isPassword});
final bool isPassword;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
  child: TextFormField(
    enableSuggestions: isPassword ? false : true,
    autocorrect: isPassword ? false : true,
    obscureText: isPassword,
    controller: myController,
    cursorColor: cursorColor,
    style: GoogleFonts.spaceMono(
      color: textColor,
    ),
    keyboardType: isPassword? TextInputType.visiblePassword : TextInputType.emailAddress,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: hintText,
      hintStyle: GoogleFonts.spaceMono(
        color: hintStyleTextColor,
      ),
      labelText: lableText,
      labelStyle: GoogleFonts.spaceMono(
        color: lableStyleTextColor,
      ),
      prefixIcon: SvgPicture.asset(
        svgIcon,
        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        height: 40,
        width: 40,
      ),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: borderColor,
          width: 1,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
          10.0,
        ),
      ),
      fillColor: textFormFieldFillColor,
      filled: true,
      suffixIcon: isPassword ? IconButton(
        icon: SvgPicture.asset(
          iPasswordVisible,
          height: 40,
          width: 40,
          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
      ) : null,
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `!` operator in multiple places, but you haven't ensured that the variables you are checking are non-null.

To fix this issue, you need to ensure nullable variables have value.

```dart
class CustomizedTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        enableSuggestions: isPassword == true ? false : true,
        autocorrect: isPassword == true ? false : true,
        obscureText: isPassword ?? true,
        ...
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "To fix this issue, you need to ensure that you are using the ! operator only on non-null variables."  Put another way, stop using !.  Instead, choose a different codepath if that variable is null.